# Interpretation BDS test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, nonlinear

I used BDS test for testing non-linearity in my dataset.

- $H_0$ : my series are linearly dependent
- $H_1$ : my series are not linearly dependent

Here is BDS test result with $\epsilon = (0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)$ and $m$ in range $[2,5]$.

```
     BDS Test 

data:  My data 

Embedding dimension =  2 3 4 5 

Epsilon for close points =   5.7801 11.5601 17.3402 23.1203

Standard Normal = 
[ 5.7801 ] [ 11.5601 ] [ 17.3402 ] [ 23.1203 ]
[ 2 ]     1.0670     -1.0243      0.0629     -0.2549
[ 3 ]     3.3484     -0.2499      0.9989      0.8866
[ 4 ]     8.7794      1.1878      1.5669      1.2727
[ 5 ]    17.6653      2.3430      2.1514      1.6768

p-value = 
[ 5.7801 ] [ 11.5601 ] [ 17.3402 ] [ 23.1203 ]
[ 2 ]     0.2860      0.3057      0.9499      0.7988
[ 3 ]     0.0008      0.8027      0.3179      0.3753
[ 4 ]     0.0000      0.2349      0.1171      0.2031
[ 5 ]     0.0000      0.0191      0.0314      0.0936
```

I **reject** $H_0$ at $m=2$ and **DO NOT reject** $H_0$ at other values.

So, my questions are:

- What is the conclusion in this case?
- Do my dataset have linearity property?